# LINQ Where ... AND NOT

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to build a query with C# and EF6 which should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE (State = 'Active') 
AND NOT (ItemId = 3 AND Field = 'some text') 
AND NOT (ItemId = 7 AND Field = 'some other text')
```

The first condition is alway State = 'Active' and the following conditions can appear several times.
If I try it the following way I don't get the records I would receive with the SQL query from above.

```
var records = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.State == "Active");

foreach (var ignoreItem in ignoreList)
{
  records = records.Where(x => x.ItemId != ignoreItem.ItemId && x.Field != ignoreItem.FieldText);
}
```

Comment: `&&` should be `||`, but why don't you use the same as in SQL - `!(...)`

Comment: I didn't know that I can use Where(x => !(.....)); Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have a mistake in boolean algebra:

```
NOT (ItemId = 3 AND Field = 'some text')
```

needs to translate to

```
Where(x => !(x.ItemId == ignoreItem.ItemId && x.Field == ignoreItem.FieldText))
```

or

```
Where(x => x.ItemId != ignoreItem.ItemId || x.Field != ignoreItem.FieldText)
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that my expression was wrong the way I wrote it. I didn't know how I get it right.

Answer (score 3):

Your converted expression with `!=` is *not* the same as the original expression with `=`. [Applying DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to `^(A=a & B=b)` produces `A!=a | B!=b`, while your translation uses `A!=a & B!=b`, which is incorrect.